# sending data using ajax, blank response coming from Server Side PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.0

I am sending Data to PHP using Ajax.
But blank result receiving.

**Client Side Code**

```
 <script>
     //on click of a button, Below jQuery Ajax code running.
      var prodStock= $("#product").html(); 
            $.ajax({
                data: prodStock,
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>

    <?php 
        foreach($data['Products'] as $val){
            $pro.= $val['product_id'].':'.$val['quantity'].',';
        }
    ?>  
    <div id='product'>{<?php echo rtrim($pro, ',');?>}</div>
```

**Browser Giving:**

```
<div id="product">{18:1,10:1}</div>
```

**Server Side Code**

```
public function update(){
    if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        print_r($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

**Testing:**

If i am sending statically `data: {18:1,20:1},` in ajax then working fine. returning Array.

Comment: Doesn't that expect key=value pairs?

Comment: what is html of `product` in browser?

Comment: Browser Giving:

<div id="product">{18:1,10:1}</div>

Comment: @Musa you saying key=value&key=value&key=value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate Solution which i have tried and success.

Client Side Code:

```
<script>
     //on click of a button, Below jQuery Ajax code running.
     <?php 
        foreach($data['Products'] as $val){
            $pro.= $val['product_id'].':'.$val['quantity'].',';
        }
    ?>  

      var prodStock= $("#product").html(); 
            $.ajax({
                data: <?php echo "{".rtrim($pro, ',')."}";?>,
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                async: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    if (response) {
                        alert(response);
                    }
                }
            });
    </script>
```